# How to correct figure numbering in a Word 2010 document

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, caption

[Using MS Office Pro Plus 2010, version 14.1.7128.5000]
This problem is similar to that in [MS Word figure numbers are wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/717022/ms-word-figure-numbers-are-wrong) and [Control numbering of captions in Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/739410/control-numbering-of-captions-in-microsoft-word), but the solutions there do not work for me.

I have a single document with a series of figures.  They were initially numbered Figure 1, Figure 2, ...  All figures have proper cations.
After editing the document on another computer, the figure numbers changed to Figure 0.1, Figure 0.1, Figure 0.2, ... --the number of the 2nd figure was wrong.

I do not have track changes on; I tried selecting all the text and then Update fields, which is supposed to renumber, but it had no effect.
I tried toggling show codes; they look normal for the figure numbers, AFAICS.

**Edit**: I added one more figure & caption on my primary computer.  This was correctly numbered Figure 5. The first 4 stubbornly remain **0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.**

This is driving me crazy. How can I determine what the source of the problem is? How can I fix it?

Comment: A solution to this was found in https://superuser.com/questions/1081512/different-caption-numbering-throughout-file. Specifically, I had to go through the mis-numbered figures and edit the field codes manually from `Figure { STYLEREF 2 \s }-{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 2 }` to Figure { SEQ Figure \* ARABIC } and then manually fin the figure references and `Update Field`

Answer (score 1):

When figures are reordered it's not easy to force the figure numbers to resequence.

My approach is to designate all figures "in front of text". You can reposition and reorder them as you wish.  When they're in the right order and locations, hit Control-A (select all), right click, and select "reorder". The figure numbers will be as you wish. Then, image by image, redesignate them as you like, selecting "in line with text" or one of the many "text wrapping" choices.

This process makes the problematic little blue anchors in the left margin move readily with the figures.

I acknowledge that if you have 50 figures and want to insert more within the sequence this process might not be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check where the pictures are anchored - this impacts the numbering.

Click on the picture and you'll see a little anchor icon somewhere in the text - you can then move this to a lower paragraph to change the order.

Credit to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftWord/comments/k2m916/wrong_numbering_sequence_for_figure_caption_help/)